# how to get and compare the border style of an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to check which images on my page have in their style `border: 1px #c6c6c6 solid;`

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i].style.border == "1px #c6c6c6 solid") {
        alert(imgs[i].style.border);
    }
}
```

but I am not getting any alerts.

Comment: Is the code running on document ready or onload? Did you debug and see that `imgs[i].style.border` is? My bet it is not what you think it is. The console is your friend `console.log(imgs[i].style.border);`

Comment: @epascarello: The *debugger* built into all major browsers is an even better friend than the console. :-)

Comment: I've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pm97z/). When I use `alert( imgs[i].style.border );` inside the for loop I get an alert `1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198)`... Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is **very bad**.
If somehow the order of the properties changes, your `if` statement will be *false* and that's not what you want.

More reasonable solution would be adding a `class` to the image:

```
<img src="..." class="with-border">
```

then in the CSS:

```
img.with-border {
    border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
}
```

In your JavaScript check if the image has the specific `class`:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (-1 !== imgs[i].className.indexOf('with-border')) {
        alert(imgs[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The order does **not** matter. Any order is valid. See the specification: [A double bar (||) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/about.html#value-defs)

Comment: @Quentin good point. I didn't know that. Still, it can causes problems. If the OP is comparing the `border` property with `1px #C6C6C6 solid` it doesn't mean that `1px solid #C6C6C6` will match.